# Problema en consulta MySql

Tags: mysql, mysqli

Tengo esa tabla `bateo` en mysql

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden ver se repiten ciertos `id_jugador`, pero lo que necesito es obtener una consulta que me devuelva la suma de a, v y h por cada `id_jugador`

Tengo esta consulta:

```
SELECT nombre, apellido_paterno, apellido_materno, SUM(a) AS A, SUM(v) AS V, SUM(h) AS H, FORMAT((H/V), 3) AS PTJE 
FROM bateo INNER JOIN jugador ON bateo.id_jugador = jugador.id_jugador WHERE id_temporada = 1 AND A >= 4 
GROUP BY bateo.id_jugador ORDER BY PTJE DESC
```

Como pueden ver en la consulta solo pido que me muestre en donde la suma de A sea mayor o igual a 4, pero me esta devolviendo una consulta vacía porque esta pasándome esto??

Comment: Devuelve vacío porque no hay datos que cumplan la condición

Comment: @fredyfx y como puedo hacer para que se cumpla la condición??

Comment: Una forma poco ortodoxa: Copia y pega esos datos en un excel y aplica ahí los filtros, si ves que hay datos, entonces, debería funcionar. Si no hay datos, realiza los filtros de a pocos, por ejemplo, primero selecciona a toda la temporada 1 y mira si hay datos, luego vas agregando las demás partes como el group by.

Comment: Podrías subir la estructura de la tabla jugador?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No te esta devolviendo nada por que no se cumple la condicion "a >= 4" ya que esta condicion se aplica a cada registro y no a la suma.

Para que haga el filtro de sum(a) lo tienes que poner en la clausula `HAVING` de esta forma

```
SELECT nombre, apellido_paterno, apellido_materno, SUM(a) AS A, SUM(v) AS V, SUM(h) AS H, FORMAT((H/V), 3) AS PTJE 
  FROM bateo INNER JOIN jugador ON bateo.id_jugador = jugador.id_jugador
 WHERE id_temporada = 1
 GROUP BY bateo.id_jugador
HAVING SUM(A) >= 4 
 ORDER BY PTJE DESC
```

Comment: Exactamente así lo hice, pero le puse HAVING A >= 4